# Mapping mismatch between variables from the same grid cell structure + R

Tags: r, spatial, tmap

I created the following map with tmap.
The VCI and shp_union dataset were both created with the same grid cell structure.

However, when I map shp_union, some of the bubbles are mapped outside the grid structure. Why is that ?

I though it was just a window adjustment in R but even with a larger version of the map, the problem persists.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoXEl.png)

```
The code for the map:
`tm_shape(vci) + 
  tm_polygons(col="vcidrought_type",
          pal =c("#BCE395","#21908CFF", "#3B528BFF", "#440154FF", "#000004FF"),
          levels = labels,
          title="VCI drought types") +
  tm_shape(shp_union) +
  tm_bubbles(col = "red", border.col = "black", size = "total_conflicts",
             scale = 1,
             sizes.legend=c(400, 1000, 2000, 5000),
             legend.col.show= F,
             breaks=c(1, 100, 500, 1000, 4000),
             sizes.legend.labels= c("1 to 100", "101 to 500", "501 to 1000", "1001 and greater"),
             title.size = "Cumulated conflicts")+
  tm_scale_bar(position = c("right", "bottom"), 
               breaks = c(0,1000,2000))`
```

VCI dataset:

```
`structure(list(gid = c(100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 
100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L), country = structure(c(32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("Angola", 
"Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso (Upper Volta)", "Burundi", 
"Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", 
"Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Djibouti", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", 
"Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Ivoire", "Kenya", 
"Lesotho", "Liberia", "Madagascar (Malagasy)", "Malawi", "Mali", 
"Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", 
"Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"Sudan", "Swaziland (Eswatini)", "Tanzania (Tanganyika)", "Togo", 
"Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)"), class = "factor"), 
    xcoord.x = c(13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 
    13.75, 13.75, 13.75), ycoord.x = c(-20.25, -20.25, -20.25, 
    -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25), 
    col = c("388", "388", "388", "388", "388", "388", "388", 
    "388", "388", "388"), row = c("140", "140", "140", "140", 
    "140", "140", "140", "140", "140", "140"), gwno = c(565L, 
    565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L), km2 = c(3282.64642089, 
    3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 
    3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 
    3282.64642089), Year = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2003", 
    "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "1997", "1998"), ycoord.y = c(-20.25, 
    -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, 
    -20.25), xcoord.y = c(13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 
    13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75), VCI = c(47.6116253045889, 
    66.8255937282856, 42.5661983856788, 33.233853670267, 29.5257619689493, 
    38.4215158606475, 71.3801674476037, 45.530642912938, 28.4013691682082, 
    42.433207145104), vcidrought = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0), vcidrought_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("No drought", "Mild drought", 
    "Moderate drought", "Severe drought", "Extreme drought"), class = "factor"), 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 
    13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 
    14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 
    14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 
    14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 13.5, ymin = -20.5, 
    xmax = 14, ymax = -20), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 15L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"
), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(gid = NA_integer_, 
country = NA_integer_, xcoord.x = NA_integer_, ycoord.x = NA_integer_, 
col = NA_integer_, row = NA_integer_, gwno = NA_integer_, km2 = NA_integer_, 
Year = NA_integer_, ycoord.y = NA_integer_, xcoord.y = NA_integer_, 
VCI = NA_integer_, vcidrought = NA_integer_, vcidrought_type = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))`
```

shp_union dataset:

```
`structure(list(gid = 100467:100476, country = structure(c(32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("Angola", 
"Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso (Upper Volta)", "Burundi", 
"Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", 
"Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Djibouti", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", 
"Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Ivoire", "Kenya", 
"Lesotho", "Liberia", "Madagascar (Malagasy)", "Malawi", "Mali", 
"Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", 
"Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"Sudan", "Swaziland (Eswatini)", "Tanzania (Tanganyika)", "Togo", 
"Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)"), class = "factor"), 
    xcoord = c(13.25, 13.75, 14.25, 14.75, 15.25, 15.75, 16.25, 
    16.75, 17.25, 17.75), ycoord = c(-20.25, -20.25, -20.25, 
    -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25), 
    col = c("387", "388", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", 
    "394", "395", "396"), row = c("140", "140", "140", "140", 
    "140", "140", "140", "140", "140", "140"), gwno = c(565L, 
    565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L, 565L), km2 = c(3282.64642089, 
    3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 
    3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 3282.64642089, 
    3282.64642089), total_conflicts = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(13, 
    13, 13.5, 13.5, 13, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(13.5, 13.5, 14, 14, 13.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 14.5, 14.5, 14, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14.5, 14.5, 
    15, 15, 14.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(15, 15, 15.5, 15.5, 15, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(15.5, 15.5, 16, 16, 15.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(16, 16, 16.5, 
    16.5, 16, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L
    ))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(16.5, 
    16.5, 17, 17, 16.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(17, 17, 17.5, 17.5, 17, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 18, 18, 17.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 13, 
    ymin = -20.5, xmax = 18, ymax = -20), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(gid = NA_integer_, 
country = NA_integer_, xcoord = NA_integer_, ycoord = NA_integer_, 
col = NA_integer_, row = NA_integer_, gwno = NA_integer_, km2 = NA_integer_, 
total_conflicts = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"))`
```

Comment: Looks like the grid contains only cells which are entirely inside the landmass, i. e. excluding cells covering land and water (like along the coastline). Bubbles instead seem to have been calculated coastline grids as well. It might help to change the clipping mode for the earlier (vci that would be, I guess).

Comment: It's impossible. They have the exact same grid cells.